# Any preferably open source html compressor written in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-compression

I am looking for an HTML compressor/minimizer written in Javascript. Say, I have a Javascript variable containing some HTML code, I want to pass it to a Javascript function that will remove unecessary spaces, comments, etc... Does such tool exist? I can't find any...

Comment: It would help if you added "minifier" to your dictionary of search words.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason for a javascipt minimizer?

If you are worried about your website loading time, then why not try [head.js()](http://headjs.com/)?

You can see the change if you have a large number of libraries.

But if you have really want to minify, there is [AJAX minifier](http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/)

I used it just now and works wonderful.

Comment: AJAX Minifier does not compress HTML... This does not answer the question.